# How do I get into script mode for Python?

Tags: python, ide

I am confused as to how to get into script mode in Python's standard IDLE. I surprisingly cannot find how to get into it on Google.

Comment: What do you mean by Python's standard IDE?

Comment: If you mean IDLE, just right click and hit  `Edit with IDLE`

Comment: If by "Python's standard IDE" you mean IDLE (Python’s Integrated Development and Learning Environment), here's some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) for it. Also see [Getting Started With Python IDLE](https://realpython.com/python-idle/). The world-wide-web is your oyster.

Comment: @Haveaniceday When I do that, a [pop-up](https://imgur.com/a/vMsrWHk) shows up and when I click on the first thing, the pop-up just reappears. All of the other apps below aren't even Python related.

Comment: Hmm. IDLE might not be installed correctly or something. You could try some different IDE's and text editors, like [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), to name a few. If you have to you can even use notepad, although it is far from optimal.

Comment: @Haveaniceday Yeah, turns out I had to update Python

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean the simple editor that ships with Python, "IDLE"?

If you have an IDLE console window open already, go to file->New File, or press ctrl+N to get a window where you can write and save a python file like a text editor.

When you've written a script in that editor you can save it as you'd expect from File->Save and run it from Run->Run Module, or press F5 as a quick shortcut. It should then output any text to the IDLE console window.

Also see the comments directly beneath your question for some resources :) Happy scripting!

Comment: Well, I can't even open up the IDLE. Whenever I click on it, nothing shows up.

Comment: Did you fix this/did my answer here help in the end? I see from your other comments you got it running eventually.

Comment: it was actually that I had to reinstall Python